# foreach $FILES create post how to

Tags: wp-insert-post

I know this is probably super easy and I am overlooking something here.

I have a form on the front-end of our website where users can upload an image via a form and it creates a product in our shop.

Currently everything works fine when uploading one image, How would I make this work for when a user uploads multiple images?

In the form I changed 
`<input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" />` 
to 
`<input type="file" name="thumbnail" id="thumbnail" multiple />`and I thought wrapping the below in something like this would work:

```
if ($_FILES) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    // do necessary code
  }
}
```

But it doesn't.

Here is what I have that creates the post.  Im not sure why wrapping it in the foreach $FILES won't work?

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {


        $postTitle = trim($_POST['postTitle']);


    if($post_id)
    {
        wp_redirect(home_url());
        exit;
    }

    //random sku
$skuu = rand();

$new_post = array(
'post_title' => $skuu,
'post_content' => '', //add anything here like link to vendor or whatever
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_type' => 'product'
);


//insert and update post
$post_id = wp_insert_post($new_post);
update_post_meta($post_id, '_sku', $skuu );

if ($_FILES) {
  foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
    $newupload = insert_attachment($file,$post_id);
  }
}

//find available attributes
$avail_attributes = Array(
    'high-resolution',
    'medium-resolution',
    'low-resolution'
);

//set terms (variations and attributes)
wp_set_object_terms ($post_id, 'variable', 'product_type');
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $avail_attributes, 'pa_resolution' );


//Categories
wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, array(esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postCat'])), esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['raceCat']))), 'product_cat' );

// set variable data
$thedata = Array('pa_resolution'=>Array(
'name'=>'pa_resolution',
'value'=>'',
'is_visible' => '1',
'is_variation' => '1',
'is_taxonomy' => '1'
));

update_post_meta( $post_id,'_product_attributes',$thedata);
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_visibility', 'visible' );
update_post_meta( $post_id, '_stock_status', 'instock');
//update_post_meta( $post_id, '_product_vendors_commission', '25');

//insert variations post_type
$i=1;
while ($i<=3) {
$my_post = array(
      'post_title'    => 'Variation #' . $i . ' of ' . esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postTitle'])),
      'post_name'     => 'product-' . $post_id . '-variation-' . $i,
      'post_status'   => 'publish',
      'post_parent'   => $post_id,
      'post_type'     => 'product_variation',
      'guid'          =>  home_url() . '/?product_variation=product-' . $post_id . '-variation-' . $i,
      'post_author'   => $vendor_data->term_id
    );

    // Insert the post into the database
    wp_insert_post( $my_post );

    $variable_id = $post_id + 2;
    $variable_two = $variable_id + 1;
    $variable_three = $variable_two + 1;

    //get user prices
    global $current_user;
    $low_price = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_low_price', true);
    $medium_price = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_medium_price', true);
    $high_price = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, '_high_price', true);

    //downloadable file paths
    $download_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );
    $lowRes_src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $download_id, 'low-resolution' );
    $medRes_src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $download_id, 'medium-resolution' );
    $highRes_src  = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $download_id, 'high-resolution' );

    $low_downloadable_images = array();
    $medium_downloadable_images = array();
    $high_downloadable_images = array();

    foreach ($lowRes_src as $lowRes_url) {
        $lowRes_url = $lowRes_src[0];
        $low_downloadable_images[md5( $lowRes_url )] = $lowRes_url;
    }

    foreach ($medRes_src as $medRes_url) {
        $medRes_url = $medRes_src[0];
        $medium_downloadable_images[md5( $medRes_url )] = $medRes_url;
    }

    foreach ($highRes_src as $highRes_url) {
        $highRes_url = $highRes_src[0];
        $high_downloadable_images[md5( $highRes_url )] = $highRes_url;
    }

    //echo $rand;

    update_post_meta( $variable_id, 'attribute_pa_resolution', 'high-resolution');
    update_post_meta( $variable_id, '_price', $high_price );
    update_post_meta( $variable_id, '_regular_price', $high_price);
    update_post_meta( $variable_id, '_virtual', 'yes');
    update_post_meta( $variable_id, '_downloadable', 'yes');
    update_post_meta( $variable_id, '_file_paths', $high_downloadable_images);

    update_post_meta( $variable_two, 'attribute_pa_resolution', 'medium-resolution');
    update_post_meta( $variable_two, '_price', $medium_price );
    update_post_meta( $variable_two, '_regular_price', $medium_price);
    update_post_meta( $variable_two, '_virtual', 'yes');
    update_post_meta( $variable_two, '_downloadable', 'yes');
    update_post_meta( $variable_two, '_file_paths', $medium_downloadable_images);

    update_post_meta( $variable_three, 'attribute_pa_resolution', 'low-resolution');
    update_post_meta( $variable_three, '_price', $low_price );
    update_post_meta( $variable_three, '_regular_price', $low_price);
    update_post_meta( $variable_three, '_virtual', 'yes');
    update_post_meta( $variable_three, '_downloadable', 'yes');
    update_post_meta( $variable_three, '_file_paths', $low_downloadable_images);

    $i++;
    }


}

//attach vendor to product
$vendor = get_user_vendor();
if( isset( $vendor->slug ) && strlen( $vendor->slug ) > 0 ) {
    wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $vendor->slug, 'shop_vendor', false );
}
```

In short I just need a way for the above code to create the post for each file uploaded, instead of just one file uploaded like it currently does.. Im all out of ideas

Answer (score 0):

Got it, so I changed the name of the file input from thumbnail to thumbnail[].  Then I wrapped the above paste in a function and added this part at the top of the file and it works perfectly:

```
if ( $_FILES ) {
    $files = $_FILES['thumbnail'];
        foreach ($files['name'] as $key => $value) {
          if ($files['name'][$key]) {
          $file = array(
          'name' => $files['name'][$key],
          'type' => $files['type'][$key],
          'tmp_name' => $files['tmp_name'][$key],
          'error' => $files['error'][$key],
          'size' => $files['size'][$key]
          );

              $_FILES = array("" => $file);

              foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {
                      //call my function
                  create_var_product($file, $post_id);
              }
          }
    }
}
```